# Summation with index $1\leq i<j\leq n$

Tags: summation, notation

What does the following index notation mean?
$$
\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{1}{a_i+a_j} \tag 1
$$
Is it a short for:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^j
\Bigg (
\sum_{j=1}^n
\frac{1}{a_i+a_j}
\Bigg ) 
\qquad ?
\tag 2
$$
Or maybe:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n
\Bigg (
\sum_{j=1}^n
\frac{1}{a_i+a_j}
\Bigg ) 
\qquad ?
\tag 3
$$
Because $i$ and $j$ are natural numbers I assume the smallest numbers for $n$ must be $4$, ie. $1\leq i<j\leq 4$?

With $n=4$ in $(3)$, does it mean we have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^4
\Bigg (
\sum_{j=1}^4
\frac{1}{a_i+a_j}
\Bigg ) 
&=
\sum_{i=1}^4
\Bigg (
\frac{1}{a_i+a_1}+\frac{1}{a_i+a_2}
+\frac{1}{a_i+a_3}+\frac{1}{a_i+a_4}
\Bigg ) 
\tag 4
\\
&=\frac{3}{a_1+a_1}+\frac{3}{a_2+a_2}
+\frac{3}{a_3+a_3}+\frac{3}{a_4+a_4}
\tag 5
\end{align}

Comment: $\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}$ is short for $\sum^n_{j=1}\sum^{j-1}_{i=1}$. Also, attention, because $\sum^j_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}$ it's incorrect, because you use $j$ as a variable ranging between $1$ and $n$ in the second sum, and as the upper term of the first sum

Comment: If $j<n$ is fixed then you sum over $i$ up to $j-1$. So the sum over $i$ is the inner sum, which you then sum over $j$.

Comment: $n$ can be less than 4. If $n=2$, the sum has only one term, with $i=1$ and $j=2$. If $n<2$, then the sum has zero terms, which often by conventional is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \frac{1}{a_i+a_j}
$$
is short for
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{a_i+a_j} \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
S=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{1}{a_i+a_j} \tag 1
$$

$$\implies S=
\sum_{j=2}^n
\Bigg (
\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}
\frac{1}{a_i+a_j}
\Bigg ) 
\qquad 
\tag 2
$$

Since $S$ is symmetric in $i$ and $j$, the roles of $i$ and $j$ can be interchanged also.